# Can't send sms with laravel and simpleSoftwareio

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send an sms for test purpose and i got this error and am stuck.

> Non-static method should not be called statically

[image]

Comment: Share home controller?

Comment: Post the code, specifically from HomeController around like 32.

Comment: please don't post errors as an image, they are impossible to search! I have added the base-error to your question. Also, you should add the actual code where your error is, as we can now only guess what's going on

Answer (score 0):

your error is that the function `send()` cannot be called statically. So you should create an SMS object, and call send like `$sms_object->send()`, instead of the `SMS::send()` you seem to do.

My guess is, but as you post no code it is only a guess, that you do something like this:

```
 SMS::send($parameters);
```

but you should be doing:

```
$sms = new SMS($parameters);
$sms->someFunctionMaybe();
$sms->send();
```

Comment: `SMS::send(laravel::sms,  null, function($sms) {
        $sms->to('+2348181627943');
        });`

Comment: So as said, it seems you can't do that. It is not a static function.

Comment: how do i pull could you spoon feed me